# How to fix broken brick staircase?

Tags: brick, stairs, outdoor

Short form question: Replacing bricks of a brick stair-case (leading to house), what kind of concrete to use?

Full story:
The staircase leading to my house (from outside) had some broken bricks.  The biggest issue was the rail - as the bricks to which it is fitted came loose, the rail was no longer stable.
Since than, I used chizzle+hammer to remove the broken bricks and concrete that was holding them.  Most of the staircase is intact - but about 20 bricks from various sections of the stair-case were removed.

My next step, I think, is to buy some new bricks and concrete.  Home-Depot or Lowes are the two stores I normally would get these in.

My question is: What kind of concrete should I get?  There seem to be different types, my prime concern is that it holds well.  A long time ago I replaced one brick in same stairs, and this time I took it out, as the concrete didn't seem to hold. (It is very possible I messed up installation)

I'd like to do this myself due to budgeting issues, and I do not have any tools that a construction person might have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clarify, this staircase is entirely brick, correct? If so, you absolutely don't want to use concrete. Concrete is harder than the brick and will eventually damage the bricks.

You want to use mortar. If it's an older staircase, it's likely sanded mortar (mortar + sand).

Answer (score 1):

If it is 20 bricks, it isn't going to be expensive to fix unless you find someone who is looking to rip you off. You can get away with not buying the tools, but try to find something similar to: A trowel, striker, and a brush. Buy some Sakrete or something similar at Lowes - All purpose mortar mix, talk to the associates and try to match the color, take a piece of old concrete or mortar and tell them what it is for. You don't seem to have any experience so get the just add water stuff and follow the directions. Mix it in a large bucket/wheel barrel, flop that mud(concrete) where you want to put a brick with the trowel, insert the brick, tap it with the trowel and a level to get it as level as possible, do 20 times, strike the seems to make it look nice, when you are done brush it all off. I am sure youtube has a video for laying a brick.

If you use rock-salt on your stair-case during the winter time it will cause it to break up quicker. Try kitty-litter